# Verilog: Sampling short, external, asynchronous input signals on a FPGA

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, sampling, gpio-external-interrupt

I want to sample an external, possibly very short interrupt signal in my FPGA softcore. I did some research in some digital logic design books, and found this solution, where A is the input signal. The problem here is that it is way too short to be sampled by the synchronous flipflop shown, so a latch is used:

[image]

I am now wondering how this can be implemented in Verilog for use in a FPGA, I do not know how to tell the synthesis tool to place a latch there. How can this be done? Also, the design **doesn't** show how to reset Q - in the plot, it stays high for the rest of the example. **How do I reset the whole design to be ready for the next interrupt signal?**

**Additionally:** Do I need to put this signal through a few chained flip-flops to combat metastability, or is this design safe as-is?

Comment: You could instantiate the gates directly.

Comment: Do not fail to run any asynchronous external signal through a chain of at least two flip-flops/registers before using it with anything that runs off the FPGA clock.

Comment: That's true for signals that are longer than your clock period.  But OP's problem is a bit (no pun intended) different.

Comment: @SteveSh Yes, I was just looking at it again just now thinking it might be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect your signal to the clock input and use an async reset:

```
module see_shorty (
  input      short_signal,
  input      short_signal_clear,
  output reg short_signal_seen
  );

// You can make this negedge short_signal to detect a falling edge
// In the same way you can invert the reset signal
always @(posedge short_signal or posedge short_signal_clear)
   if (short_signal_clear)
      short_signal_seen <= 1'b0;
   else
      short_signal_seen <= 1'b1;
endmodule // see_shorty
```

Synchronize `short_signal_seen` to your clock and use the result to make a `short_signal_clear` pulse which clears the FF again. (I leave those details to you)

---

Make a reset pulse:

```
// Make a reset pulse if short signal (synced to system clock) is high
// but previously it was low 
reg  delayed_sig;        // Need previous state of signal
wire short_signal_clear;

always @(posedge clk)
   delayed_sig <= short_signal_seen_synced;

assign short_signal_clear = short_signal_seen_synced & ~delayed_sig;
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks good! I would personally use a chain of two FF to synchronize the signal to my clock domain, is that sufficient? :)

Comment: Yes. That is the norm. Then a  third FF with an exor to make the reset pulse.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "exor"? I would have generated the pulse in Verilog by asserting the reset signal, and with the next clock edge, deasserting it, like a small state machine. Is there a simpler way? :)

Comment: Sorry, probably not an exor gate. I'll update the code

Answer (score 1):

How bout something like this?  The clock is your local clock, common to all the flip flops.  R is the reset (usually power on) for the FFs.

The glitch filter is optional.

[image]

**Answer to OP's Question**

S is just the SET input of the flip flop.

Comment: What is the "S" input from the first flip flop? Will this catch signals that are shorter than the clock period and do no coincide with the clock edges?